# Where could i find the intended travel for my specific mtb suspension forks

Tags: mountain-bike, fork, suspension, resource

I have a Akela forged CR-MO mtb suspension fork that im trying to find the specs for. I'm building a bicycle for the first time and need forks for it. I have a few forks laying around. I know the amount of travel meant for my bike frame buy I can't find any source on how or where to find out what the travel is on any of my forks to know if they are compatible or not. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you just measure the distance between the bottom of the crown and top of the lower?  Might not be 100% accurate, but probably close enough for tolerance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Measure the fork's axle to crown dimension in uncompressed state, and then in fully compressed state. The difference is the travel.

Usually the practical way of doing this is to measure the length of the exposed stanchion when the fork is uncompressed, and then again when fully compressed. It can be a little clumsy, but you're typically only trying to figure out what travel "class" it falls in, eg 120, 100, 80, etc, so precision doesn't matter much.

Some frame specs use the uncompressed axle to crown as the number, not travel per se. Sometimes this is also known as "fork length."